# How best to extend UK Partner Visa from U.S.?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, visa

I have a UK partner Visa that is expiring on June 13, 2019. I am a U.S. citizen currently living in NYC. My partner is British and we have a 2.5 year old son.

What is the best (easiest and most cost effective) way to renew my Partner Visa? I have not worked in the UK since February 2017. A job might be opening up there and I've indicated that I do not require sponsorship.

Answer (score 1):

> When you can apply to extend or switch
>   You can extend or switch at any time before your current permission to stay in the UK expires.
>
> You must live in the UK for a certain amount of time before you’re eligible for settlement (‘indefinite leave to remain’) - check how much time you need before you extend your visa.
>
> If you’re extending to stay with the same family member, you’ll only get up to 28 days left on your current stay added to your new visa. https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa

You can fill out the paperwork, but it looks like they do not usually extend the period very far if you are outside the UK.